# C : differences between prototype declaration in header and function declaration for implementation?

Tags: c, prototype, declaration

I was wondering about little differences between declaration of function prototypes in headers and in .c files. I have a header with some prototype functions and a some .c files with real implementation of these functions. I made some changes in the header, only added "__restrict" qualifier (recognized by gcc). My question is do I have to put the "__restrict" qualifier in .c files to (currently the code compile so I guess the answer is no, but some precision would be appreciated).

Does this work for every C qualifier? Can I add some "const" or "volatile" in header without having to do the same in .c files?

currently in header :

```
int myfunc_gettype (const mytype *__restrict, int *__restrict);
```

and in implementation file :

```
int myfunc_gettype(const mytype *attr, int *type)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **must**. The mismatch invokes undefined behavior. Is there some reason why you want to have separate declarations in the header and at definition?

Note well, that the keyword is `restrict` as opposed to `__restrict` which is a vendor extension (hint: look at the `_`'s before the keyword name). You should stick to the standard version for portability.

Comment: in fact the restrict keyword is C99 and the __restrict is just catch by gcc with i guess the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, if I have the restrict qualifier in the header and not in the implementation, will the pointer be "restrict" anyway or not?

Comment: You are invoking UB. It may actually cause the pointer to be restrict qualified. The standard C++ keyword is 'restrict', why use __restrict?

Comment: The restrict keyword is a type qualifier for pointers and is a formal part of the C99 standard.In code that cannot be compiled with C99, use either __restrict or __restrict__ to enable the keyword as a GCC extension.

Comment: I have one header file for my library and one .c file per function so I was just wondering if I can avoid modifying every .c files (which is a lot of files) and just modify the header only.

Comment: UB = Undefined Behavior -- a malformed program (and much worse). No, can't be that lazy :)

Comment: Note well: Since it invokes UB, the compiler is not supposed to produce a diagnostic. Don't fall for this, though.

Comment: @dirkgently : I'm no that lazy, but I tried to compile after editing just the header and as it compile, I just asked myself this question :)

Comment: @claferri: When you rely on vendor extensions, you lose portability. (That bit about laziness was just a joke. No offense, please!)

Comment: @dirkgently : you must be right about portability issue, I'm going to see if I can have C99 code instead of using __restrict, and i'm not offensed of course ;)

Comment: @dirkgently Can you quote the part of the spec that you think makes this undefined behaviour? I find it strange that GCC wouldn't generate a diagnostic for this case, since it does in every other case of prototype/implementation mismatch. Section §6.7.3.7 of the C99 spec states: "The intended use of the restrict qualifier (like the register storage class) is to promote optimization, and deleting all instances of the qualifier from all reprocessing translation units composing a conforming program does not change its meaning (i.e., observable behavior).".

Comment: Since `restrict` is just a promise to not pass pointers to overlapping memory in specific function arguments, the only thing that should invoke UB is breaking that promise by misusing the function. Having `restrict` qualifiers in a header prototype and not in the implementation doesn't seem like UB to me.

Answer (score -1):

With gcc 4.0.1, it depends on whether the const is pointless:

```
// Who cares, compiles fine, but irks the maintenance programmer.

// f.h
int f(const int i);

// f.c
int f(int i) { return i += 42; }


// No no no no Your Types Conflict gcc will not stand for it

// f.h
int f(const int *pi);

// f.c
int f(int *pi) { return (*pi)+= 42; }
```

Comment: The question wasn't "is this legal" or even "is this acceptable practice"; it was "will it work."

Answer (score -2):

NOTE: You haven't actually added the 'restrict' qualifier.  You just have different (optional) variable names in the prototype.

As to your question, most good C compilers will catch this bug and throw a warning/error if the non-matching prototype is #included with the implementation.  If you have mismatching prototypes, you may see problems ranging from subtle to instant crash.

Comment: you mean __restrict is an optional variable name in the prototype? I'm pretty sure you're wrong with gcc.

Comment: In fact, I was right : "The restrict keyword is a type qualifier for pointers and is a formal part of the C99 standard.In code that cannot be compiled with C99, use either __restrict or __restrict__ to enable the keyword as a GCC extension."

Comment: Since it compiles, it must be just a qualifier; you can't have two arguments with the same name.  I wondered at first, but I think this argument is decisive - assuming the code does compile as claimed.

Comment: @Jonathan : yes, before using the __restrict qualifier, I first used restrict without -std=c99 and gcc complain about having two arguments with the same name, then i remember i couldn't compile with -std=c99 for the moment and decided to use gcc extension __restrict instead.